# SOCKS in C/C++ or another language?

Tags: c++, python, c, perl, socks

How do i add SOCKS support to my application? and where can i get the libs?

any help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library. It contains [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html#boost_asio.examples.socks_4) with SOCKS4 protocol implementation.

Answer (score -3):

VC++ has extensive support if you want to try on Windows.

Google "Windows sockets for beginners msdn", great info for windows sockets...

If linux, try C sockets by beej... Just google beej's guide for sockets...